# Radial distribution function in a plane

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

I have a three-dimensional system of N particles. The particle positions are described by three coordinates $x$, $y$, $z$. For this system, I can calculate the Radial Distribution Function (RDF) in 3D. But my question is:

Is it in principle allowed to calculate the RDF of this system in one of the planes say, $x$-$y$, $y$-$z$ or $z$-$x$  plane? Is there any theoretical restriction?

The RDF is interpreted as the ratio of two-particle density in a system having correlation to the two particle density in an ideal system. If I want to calculate the RDF in one of the planes as I have mentioned above, can I take the homogeneous single particle density in that plane to be $N/A$ where $A$ is the area of the plane?

P.S.: The system is actually moving in 3D, but I want to consider projection of the system in one plane, say, $x$-$y$, $y$-$z$ or $z$-$x$ and then calculate RDF in that plane.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you could not project the RDF to a plane?

Comment: In the definition of RDF, there appears a homogeneous single particle density for the system under consideration. So, if the system is a 3D one, there appears a volume single-particle density ( say, $\rho$) or, if the system is a 2D one there appears areal single-particle density ($\sigma$). I am doubtful about projecting RDF onto a plane, because I am not sure about the single-particle density that I should be using in that case. Given single particle density, $\rho=\frac{N}{V}$ in 3D, what is the expression for homogeneous single particle density in say, $x-y$ plane ? Is it $\frac{N}{A}$ ?